# Why wont my routing work?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and attempting to get my routing to work. It is coming up with nothing.

I'm using dreamweaver, it prompts me with the error "angular is not defined" but the js file is placed after the angular ones in the header?

When I click the links it does not direct me to anything and nothing is viewed. I suspect that either the code is broken or I am not setting up the ng-view correctly.

Would anyone be able to advise on how to get it working?

```
 <header class="hidden-sm" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
    family=Droid+Serif|Roboto:300" 
     rel="stylesheet">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

 </header>
```

```
<nav class="container" id="main-nav">
     <ul id="navlist">
        <li class="navli"><a href="#/build">Build a PC</a></li>-
        <li class="navli"><a href="#/about">About Us</a></li>-
        <li class="navli"><a href="#/"><img src="images/hive32color.png" 
     alt="bee-logo"></a></li>-
        <li class="navli"><a href="#/contact">Contact Us</a></li>-
        <li class="navli"><a href="#/inside">Inside our Machines</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>



 <section class="container">

   <div class="col-lg-9" ng-view>


   </div>

    <aside class="col-lg-3">

    </aside>

   </section>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller.js"></script>
  </body>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','RouteControllers']);

angular.module('myApp').config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
         templateUrl:'templates/about.html',
          controller:'AboutController'
        })
    .when('/build',{
         templateUrl:'templates/build.html',
          controller:'BuildController'
        })
    .when('/contact',{
         templateUrl:'templates/contact.html',
          controller:'ContactController'
        })
    .when('/inside',{
         templateUrl:'templates/inside.html',
          controller:'InsideController'
        });

});
```

edit: I realised i was not running a web server, i have done that now and it still is not working!

Comment: the ng-app is defined ?

Comment: Yes sorry, i cut that off by mistake. It reads in the body tag ng-app="myApp"

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to add "/" after "#" in href. Just try href="#Contact" for your reference https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Comment: Will do, originally it was '/contact' because I was under the impression $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); rids the URL of the # sign. I will make the change.